# Get different and common items in two arrays with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

For example, I have two arrays:

```
var list1 = string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
var list2 = string[] {"2", "3", "4"};
```

What I'm trying to do is -

1. Get common items from `list1` and `list2` (eg. {"2", "3", "4"})
2. Get different items `list1` and `list2` (eg. {"1", "5", "6"})

So I've tried with LINQ and -

```
var listDiff = list1.Except(list2); //This gets the desire result for different items
```

But,

```
var listCommon = list1.Intersect(list2); //This doesn't give me desire result. Comes out as {"1", "5", "6", "2", "3", "4"};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It should work. `list1.Intersect(list2)` returns "2", "3", "4".

Comment: You are missing 2 `new` in your syntax. That won't compile. Use: `var list2 = new string[] {"2", "3", "4"};`

Comment: Silly me. In fact, Intersect works, just that the other part to output the array to text box was messing up. Thanks all!

Comment: If `list1` and `list2` already exist, the above systax is fine. This works for me...

Comment: Ye Myat Aung - You should see a _delete_ link under the question.

Comment: just commenting to let the people who closed it know it helped me a few times, and 25 people who upvoted the answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Somehow you have got that result from somewhere else. (Perhaps you are writing out the contents of `listDIff` first, and thought that it was from `listCommon`.) The `Intersect` method *does* give you the items that exists in both lists:

```
var list1 = new string[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
var list2 = new string[] {"2", "3", "4"};
var listCommon = list1.Intersect(list2);
foreach (string s in listCommon) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
```