# Calculating the number of similar words between two strings in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, algorithm, t-sql

I am planning to write a TSQL function of two input strings and a percentage of words similarity as an output, For example :

```
SELECT [dbo].[FN_CalcSimilarWords]('Golden horses hotel','Hotel Golden Horses')
```

Returns :

```
3/3
```

or

```
SELECT [dbo].[FN_CalcSimilarWords]('Golden horses','Golden horses Malaysia')
```

Returns :

```
2/3
```

I was thinking about looping and comparing the words after parsing the strings to [This split function](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666620/T-SQL-Most-Practical-Split-Function), Any other ideas for a better performance?

Comment: SQL is not really strong at string manipulation, you might want to consider a CLR routine if you are allowed to install one on your server.

Comment: @Sparky, Yes i can install it, any ideas or useful links to implement a solution?

Comment: There are links here on stack overflow, it is actually pretty easy in C#,    Here is one such link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10648141/get-different-and-common-items-in-two-arrays-with-linq

Comment: unfortunately, I am limited to SQL, for some reasons, I don't want to do that in C#.

Comment: If you are limited to SQL, see my answer below.  Use a split function to create two temporary tables and than join them.   The slowest part will be the split function, but probably not noticeable unless you have a very large word list.

Comment: I have two hotels databases of 200,000 in each to compare, i expect a slow performance because of the Split function, that's why i am looking for a better way.

Comment: Where are the words stored?   How often are they updated?  If the words are in a string field and you can live with periodic updates, I would suggest creating a SQL job to do the split at some pre-defined intervals (say hourly) and then have your function do the comparison (as shown below) against the real tables.

Comment: what would the expected result for the strings 'horse horse horse' and 'horse' be. How do you come up with your strange 3/3 and 2/3 ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, It's a percentage,  3 of 3 words are matched, and 2 of 3 words are matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it in SQL, here is an approach I would take.

Create two temporary tables, using a split routine, called Words1 and Words2

Now join the tables and get the count, i.e.

```
select count(*) 
from Words1 w1 
join Words2 w2 on w1.word=w2.word
```

Let SQL do it the way it is optimized for

Here is how to get counts from both tables

```
select count(distinct w1.word) as Matches,
       count(distinct w1.word) as FromW1,
       count(distinct w2.word) as FromW2
    from #Words1 w1 
    left join #Words2 w2 on w1.word=w2.word
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This will only return the count of similar words , Is there any way to also return the count of Words1 and Words2 without re-calling the Split function?

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, However it's returning incorrect results, Matches and FromW1 are always equal.

Comment: Matches will always be equal, but the code assumes #words1 is larger than words 2.   I'll adapt the code shortly to return the larger of the two tables counts

Answer (score 3):

With this solution I am assuming you want duplicates to be removed. Switching first and second parameter makes no difference to result.

It returns a value, not a percentage since functions can only return 1 value or a table. I assume you want values between 0 and 1 making 2/3 = 0.67 or 67 percent if you multiply by 100.

```
CREATE function f_functionx
(
  @str1 varchar(2000),
  @str2 varchar(2000)
)
returns decimal(5,2)
as
BEGIN
DECLARE @returnvalue decimal(5,2)
DECLARE @list1 table(value varchar(50))
INSERT @list1
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(@str1, ' ', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)

DECLARE @list2 table(value varchar(50))
INSERT @list2
SELECT t.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(2000)')
FROM (
    SELECT x = CAST('<t>' + 
        REPLACE(@str2, ' ', '</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
) a
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/t') t(c)


;WITH isect as
(
  SELECT count(*) match FROM
  (
    SELECT value FROM @list1
    INTERSECT
    SELECT value FROM @list2
  ) x
), total as
(
  SELECT max(cnt) cnt
  FROM
  (
    SELECT count(distinct value) cnt FROM @list1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT count(distinct value) FROM @list2
  ) x
)
SELECT 
  @returnvalue = cast(isect.match as decimal(9,2)) / total.cnt 
FROM total
CROSS JOIN isect

RETURN @returnvalue
END

GO
```

You call the function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.f_functionx('Golden horses', 'Golden horses')
SELECT dbo.f_functionx('Golden horses', 'Golden horses XX')
```

Returns:

```
1
0.67
```

Comment: It seems a genius answer, unfortunately I couldn't compare the performance because most of the records contains `&`.
SQL is throwing :
`XML parsing: ... illegal name character`, I believe i have to replace it with `&amp;`

Answer (score 1):

Original Answer :
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f45cc/6)

I saw this technique at [PTR Blog](http://www.ptr.co.uk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Extracting-All-The-Words-From-a-String-In-A-Database-Query1.pdf)

**EDIT**

Amended to address issues in the comments from @t-clausen.dk:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f45cc/6)

**MS SQL Server 2012 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE StringTable 
(
    Id INT IDentity,
    String varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO StringTable
VALUES ('xx xx Golden horses Malaysia'),
        ('xx xx xx xx xx')
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH StringsCTE 
AS
(
    SELECT ID,String As StringValue, 
            CASE CHARINDEX(' ', String)
                WHEN 0 THEN String
                ELSE LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(' ',String) -1)
            END AS Word,
            1 as Position,
            CASE CHARINDEX(' ',String)
                WHEN 0 THEN ''
                ELSE RIGHT(String, LEN(String) - CHARINDEX(' ',String))
            END AS RestOfLine
    FROM StringTable
    UNION ALL

    SELECT Id,S.StringValue, 
            CASE CHARINDEX(' ',RestOfLine)
                WHEN 0 THEN RestOfLine
                ELSE LEFT(RestOfLine, CHARINDEX(' ',RestOfLine) -1)
            END, 
            Position + 1, 
            CASE CHARINDEX(' ',RestOfLine)
                WHEN 0 THEN ''
                ELSE RIGHT(RestOfLine, LEN(RestOfLine) - CHARINDEX(' ',RestOfLine))
            END
    FROM StringsCTE S
    WHERE s.RestOfLine != ''
),
WordsPerString
As
(
    SELECT S.Id, COUNT(s.Word) As NumberOfWords
    FROM StringsCTE S
    GROUP BY S.Id
)
SELECT COUNT(*) As Matches, (SELECT MAX(NumberOfWords) FROM WordsPerString) as Total
FROM StringsCTE S1
INNER JOIN StringsCTE S2
    ON S1.Word = S2.Word AND S1.Id <> S2.Id
WHERE S1.Id = 1 AND 
    NOT EXISTS -- Not already matched
  (SELECT * FROM StringsCTE S3 WHERE S3.Word = S2.Word AND S3.Id <> S1.ID AND S3.Position < S2.Position)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f45cc/6/0)**:

```
| MATCHES | TOTAL |
|---------|-------|
|       2 |     5 |
```

Comment: Try these two values in stringtable: 'xx xx Golden horses Malaysia',       'xx xx xx xx xx', it will return 5 columns with 10 matches. So it has 200 % match

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Updated answer to address your issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restrictions around deploying CLR assemblies, you might try this route and compare performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about having an exact count of common items you could use SQL Server FullText search capability. Both the `ContainsTable` and `FREETEXT` functions return a Rank. See details here

[Full Text Ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245.aspx)